# Bash last index of

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching

Sorry for the lame bash question, but I can't seem to be able to work it out.

I have the following simple case:

- I have variable like `artifact-1.2.3.zip`
- I would like to get a sub-string between the hyphen and the last index of the dot (both exclusive).

My bash skill are not too strong. I have the following:

```
a="artifact-1.2.3.zip"; b="-"; echo ${a:$(( $(expr index "$a" "$b" + 1) - $(expr length "$b") ))}
```

Producing:

```
1.2.3.zip
```

How do I remove the `.zip` part as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$ a="artifact-1.2.3.zip"; a="${a#*-}"; echo "${a%.*}"
```

‘`#`*pattern*’ removes *pattern* so long as it matches the *beginning* of `$a`.
The syntax of *pattern* is similar to that used in filename matching.
In our case,

- `*` is any sequence of characters.
- `-` means a literal dash.
- Thus `#*-` matches everything up to, and including, the *first* dash.
- Thus `${a#*-}` expands to whatever `$a` would expand to,
  except that `artifact-` is removed from the expansion,
  leaving us with `1.2.3.zip`.

Similarly, ‘`%`*pattern*’ removes *pattern* so long as it matches the *end* of the expansion.
In our case,

- `.` a literal dot.
- `*` any sequence of characters.
- Thus `%.*` is everything including the *last* dot up to the end of the string.
- Thus if `$a` expands to `1.2.3.zip`,
  then `${a%.*}` expands to `1.2.3`.

Job done.

The man page content for this is as follows (at least on my machine, YMMV):

```
       ${parameter#word}
       ${parameter##word}
              The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as  in  pathname
              expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of
              parameter, then the result of  the  expansion  is  the  expanded
              value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``#''
              case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted.
              If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied
              to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion  is  the
              resultant  list.   If parameter is an array variable subscripted
              with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each
              member  of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
              list.

       ${parameter%word}
       ${parameter%%word}
              The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as  in  pathname
              expansion.   If  the  pattern  matches a trailing portion of the
              expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is
              the  expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pat-
              tern (the ``%'' case)  or  the  longest  matching  pattern  (the
              ``%%''  case)  deleted.   If  parameter  is  @ or *, the pattern
              removal operation is applied to  each  positional  parameter  in
              turn,  and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is
              an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the  pattern  removal
              operation  is  applied  to each member of the array in turn, and
              the expansion is the resultant list.
```

HTH!

**EDIT**

Kudos to @x4d for the detailed answer.
Still think people should RTFM though.
If they don't understand the manual,
then post another question.

Comment: Any explanation or related document listed here would be better.

Comment: RTFM. To be fair the man page is very large. Look for two consecutive hashes in that file and you will be in the right area (`/##` command in _less_)

Comment: "RTFM" is not in the spirit of SO.  Answers should be curated and complete, quoting the relevant portion of the manual if needed.

Comment: Kudos to @k4d for the detailed answer. Still think people should RTFM though. If they don't understand the manual, then post another question.

Answer (score 37):

The `bash` man page section titled "**Variable Substitution**" describes using `${var#pattern}`, `${var##pattern}`, `${var%pattern}`, and `${var%%pattern}`.

Assuming that you have a variable called `filename`, e.g.,

```
filename="artifact-1.2.3.zip"
```

then, the following are pattern-based extractions:

```
% echo "${filename%-*}"
artifact

% echo "${filename##*-}"
1.2.3.zip
```

Why did I use `##` instead of `#`?

If the filename could possibly contain dashes within, such as:

```
filename="multiple-part-name-1.2.3.zip"
```

then compare the two following substitutions:

```
% echo "${filename#*-}"
part-name-1.2.3.zip

% echo "${filename##*-}"
1.2.3.zip
```

Once having extracted the version and extension, to isolate the version, use:

```
% verext="${filename##*-}"
% ver="${verext%.*}"
% ext="${verext##*.}"
% echo $ver
1.2.3
% echo $ext
zip
```

Comment: I will try this as well! Thank you for the detailed description.

Answer (score 4):

Using Bash RegEx feature:

```
>str="artifact-1.2.3.zip"
[[ "$str" =~ -(.*)\.[^.]*$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
string=${a="artifact-1.2.3.zip"; b="-"; echo ${a:$(( $(expr index "$a" "$b" + 1) - $(expr length "$b") ))}}

substring=${string:0:4}
```

The last step removes the last 4 characters from the string. There's some more info on [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: +1: Although it will tie me to a three-letter extension. I will accept bobbogo's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, no problem, it's not a very portable solution, but I like to keep things simple :). Bobbogo's solution is the way to go.